# How can I Resize the MKCircleView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am Trying to Resize MkCircle Through finger touch. How can I start this? can any one suggest me?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 4):

I draw the custom circle above the map view with same radius look like circle.

Finding edge point of MKcirlce

1. convert center point CLLocationCoordinate2D to MKMapPoint

MKMapPoint centerMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(centerCoordinate)

1. Calculate MKMapSize of the circle and get width

   double circleMapSize = mkCircle.boundingMapRect.size.width

3.create a point on the perimeter of the circle.

```
MKMapPoint leftMostPoint = MKMapPointMake(centerMapPoint.x - circleMapSize/2.0, centerMapPoint.y)
```

1. Now get CLLocationCoordinate2D point from leftMostPoint

   CLLocationCoordinate2D leftMostCoordinateOnCircle = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(leftMostPoint)

So now i have center point and edge point then convert it to (x,y) of ios coordinates.

```
CGPoint myPoint = [self.MapView convertCoordinate:originalCoordinate toPointToView:self.MapView];

CGPoint edgePoint = [self.MapView convertCoordinate:originalCoordinate toPointToView:self.MapView];
```

then i calculate distance b/w those two points using pythagoras theorem

```
int distnce1=sqrt(powf(edgePoint.x- myPoint.x, 2) + powf(edgePoint.y-myPoint.y, 2));

            int finalWidth=2*distnce1;
```

Then i set distance to custom circle width and height

after pich Gesture end again i try to get edge lattitude and longitude of custom circle by using circle maths

```
float x = circleView.frame.size.width/2 * sin(0)+circleView.center.x;
        float y = circleView.frame.size.width/2 * cos(0)+circleView.center.y;
```

convert x,y into coordinates

CLLocationCoordinate2D select_coordinate = [self.MapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.view];

then i find distance b/w new coordinates and center point of MKCircle then change the radius of MKCirlce equal to Distance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach which might be simplest is to actually draw the circle yourself above the map view, on a separate transparent view which responds to touch events. Then, when drawing is complete, hide that view but add an actual `MKCircle` to the map view with the same graphical settings.

Typically it's easier to handling drawing/gestures outside of the map view for things like this.

Comment: Thanks for Your Response. Yes offCourse I am trying that way but how to convert MKCircle radius to custom View Width.Could you please suggest me.